# Compile：error LNK2001

Tags: c++

I create a class in Vec.h like this:

```
#include <VECTOR>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Vec:public vector<T>  
{
public:
    Vec():vector<T>(){}
    Vec(int s):vector<T>(s){}
    T& operator[](int i){return at(i);}
    const T& operator[](int i) const {return at(i);}
    ~Vec();
};
```

in the main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Vec<int> test(2);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I compile them,it show:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Vec<int>::~Vec<int>        (void)" (??1?$Vec@H@@QAE@XZ)
Debug/CPlusTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

My compilation toos is VC6.0.
How can I do?

Update:
Sorry! I'd not copy the entire "main.cpp", it should be that:

```
#include <string>
#include <IOSTREAM>
#include "Vec.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Vec<int> test(2);
    return 0;
}
```

and now the error is because I dit not realize "~Vec();"
so,modify this Vec.h like this:

`~Vec(){}`

Compiled successfully!

Comment: A) what is header `VECTOR`? B) Why don't you include `Vec.h` in `main.cpp`? C) You need an implementation for `~Vec()`

Comment: Add an implementation of `~Vec()`.  And once you get that working, remove `using namespace std` from your header file.  `using` declarations in a header file are bad juju.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include <VECTOR>`

I'm assuming you meant to include `#include <vector>`.

Unresolved external ? You did not implement `~Vec(void);` only a declaration exists. Please implement the destructor or simply do not declare it.

Also for a better style I would recommend deleting the `using namespace std;` and use `std::vector<T>` instead.

Another style issue is your `return 0;` in the main function. Please use `EXIT_SUCCESS` instead.


To your edit:
Told you a implementation is needed. Also you include your headers very strange.
`#include <IOSTREAM>`
What's this ? Please use the usual style form: `#include <iostream>`. The include may work, but it looks very strange.